# How to run an application with program arguments containing spaces in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

On a (Linux) command line I start a Java class je3.gui.ShowBean with commandline arguments containin spaces the following way:

```
    $ cd ~/workspace/JavaExamles/bin
    $ java je3.gui.ShowBean javax.swing.JButton 'text=Hello World!'
```

The last parameter containes a space ('text=Hello World!'). Whitespaces split the commandline into different arguments. If I want to have a space within an argument, I have to quote the parameter it or escape the whitespace with a backslash.

The arguments of main() run on commandline would be:

```
    args[0] = "javax.swing.JButton"
    args[1] = "text=Hello World"
```

But when gui.ShowBean is startet within eclipse, the arguments are:

```
    args[0] = "javax.swing.JButton"
    args[1] = "'text=Hello"
    args[2] = "World!"
```

Which is actually not what I want to have.

How can I achive the same behavior as on commandline within eclipse?

Comment: tried double quotes ? "text=Hello World!" ?

Comment: I tried single quote but not double quote. Double quoutes work.

Comment: It was actually a good question and the answer helped me. I was also using single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that, with Eclipse, you run ShowBean with the argument text=Hello World! and not "text=Hello World!"?

Comment: I tried single quotes like on shell (`'text=Hello World'`), it didn't work. Double quotes (`"text=Hello World!"`) work.

Comment: Right.  Double quotes work (in Eclipse v.MARS)